# How can I upload file with csrf token in post request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to send 3 files and 3 text input to server.

code

```
 <form action="/route" id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
       <input type="text" name="docName1" >
       <input type="file" name="file1">
       <input type="text" name="docName2" >
       <input type="file" name="file2">
       <input type="text" name="docName3" >
       <input type="file" name="file3">
</form>
```

When I submit the form it shows error that csrf token is invalid - how can I send files with csrf token?

Comment: Where and how are you generating the PHP constant `csrfToken`? Does it have a value when you inspect the form using the console tools?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i am using nodejs

Comment: Sorry - misread that `<%=` and thought that was the PHP tag.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i am using ejs template with nodejs